# C++ increasing, decreasing numbers with "?:"

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

I though it would be nice to learn how to make a code with "?:" in C++ that first increases number, when it reaches 100, it decreases, when it reaches 0, it increases again.

Ok so to clarify: Start number: 1, should write 1 - 100, then at 100, 100, 99, 98, 97 to 0, and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
int number = 1;
string sign = "plus";
for (int i = 700; i > 0; i--) {
    (number==0?sign="plus":(number==100?sign="minus":(sign=="plus"?number++:number--)));
    cout << number;
    usleep(3000);
}
}
```

WELL! it sure isnt easy.
(Code above does not work, give error: cannot convert char to int)

THE QUESTION: It doesnt work, how to make it work?

This is not a homework..

Comment: Here's an idea: if you don't know what the effect of `++` and `--` will be and you have to ask on Stack Overflow, *stop using it!* Just write a regular `if` statement; it's guaranteed to work and *everyone* will understand it.

Comment: Hmmmmmm but I wanted to use a short code with "?:" to rotate a cube later on.. And I want it to be short.

Comment: You shouldn't use the ternary conditional for normal *statements*. Instead, you should only use it for conditional *expressions*, like `const int a = flag ? 2 : 1;`.

Comment: @user1272320: "I want it to be short." Tough. Do it right; stop trying to confuse the compiler. So what if it isn't "short"; it will be *comprehensible* (and you know, actually work), which is far more important.

Comment: "how to make it work" [in one expression] - I don't know.  "should I make it work in one expression" - No.

Comment: Once the `number` reaches 100 it won't be decremented.

Comment: @user1272320 writing shorter length code never should be a reason to do anything. Writing understandable code with a specific purpose is a more noble goal. The compiler is going to replace and optimize your statements anyway and probably a lot better than your average developer. If longer compile times is a concern buy a better computer as that is infinitely less expensive than the cost of development time caused by "short code".

Comment: You should never write code like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many novice programmers assumes that the ternary operator `?:` is just a short-hand if-statement, which is true in many cases (from the novice developers perspective). But there are limitations, and they are not at all the same thing..

The evaluated result of the ternary operator has to be the same *Type* (or convertible to one or the other) no matter if the statement tested is true or false.

---

```
#include <string>

int
main (int argc, char *argv)
{
  std::string s;
  0 == 0 ? s = "123": 123;
}
```

In this self-contained example (which fails to compile to easily prove my point) we get the following error;

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
foo.cpp:7:23: error: no match for ternary 'operator?:' in 'true ? s.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"123")) : 123'
```

This is because the expression will evalute to a `std::string&` if the statement is true, and an `int` if it's false. Two different types depending on which the evaluated expression is true or not? **Not** allowed.

The compiler therefore tries to implicitly convert either side so that a match can be found, but it couldn't find any suitable conversion and we get the error thrown in our face.

---

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  0 == 0 ? "123": 123;
}
```

The above snippet will generate a much nicer compile error than we had earlier (when trying to compile it will `g++`). And as stated in this post; both result operands of `?:` needs to be of the same type.

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
foo.cpp:4:19: error: operands to ?: have different types 'const char*' and 'int'
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I word my posts to fit the askers level of knowledge. Though I'm ashamed of writing "return" instead of "evaluate", that one is on me (I blame the language barrier) - and it's now taken care of. Regarding "which is true in many cases" I've added "from the novice developers perspective" to clear out any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem isn't with `++` and `--`. Your problem is your abuse of the `?:` operator.

`?:` is not a replacement for an `if` statement. It is first and foremost an *expression*. Expressions evaluate to values, which have types. Since `?:` can evaluate to two values, C++ requires that either both values are the same type or the second value is convertible to the first.

`sign="minus"` is an expression and it has a type. As does `(sign=="plus"?number++:number--)`. But they're not the *same* type. And they're not convertible to one another. So C++ says that your code doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int number = 1;
    int direction = +1;
    for (int i = 700; i > 0; i --) {
        direction = direction > 0 
            ? (number < 100 ? +1 : -1)
            : (number > 0  ? -1 : +1);
        number += direction;
        std::cout << number << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not using the ternary operator quite the way you're going for...

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<700;++i)
        std::cout << (i/100%2?99-i%100:i%100+1) << ' ';
}
```

And not using it at all:

```
int main() {
    for(int i=0;i<700;++i)
        std::cout << abs((i+101)%200-100) << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
number==100 ? (sign="minus") : ( sign=="plus" ? number++ : number-- ) ;
```

and it's because, if the expression the conditional evaluates to is not used, the second statement will be promoted to the first one's type (or the other way around).

The first expression's type is `std::string`. The second one evaluates to `int`. The compiler tries to promote `int` to `string` and it obviously fails.

If you insist on keeping it like this, you can hack it a bit:

```
number==100 ? (sign="minus") : ( sign=="plus" ? (number++,"") : (number--,"") ) ;
```

**I hope you don't.**

#### Use `if` for this one.

Comment: Hmm your hack didnt work, but I suppose I'll listen to your advise, aff.

Comment: @user1272320 it does compile: http://ideone.com/L9sMk You also accepted an incorrect answer.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's not incorrect, and please see my comment and edits of the post in question.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore according to me the answer was never incorrect, though on some levels I could agree with the fact that the wording was a bit misleading in places. But those misunderstandings would have gone away by reading the full post, since everything was there to begin with. Thanks for letting me know though..

Answer (score 0):

As others have told you, you are abusing the `?:` operator.  But worse than that, if you substitute your use of it with equivilent `if` statements, you will see that you also have logic errors as well:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main () { 
    int number = 1; 
    string sign = "plus"; 
    for (int i = 700; i > 0; i--) { 
        if (number==0) // <-- never happens!
            sign="plus";
        else {
            if (number==100) // <-- when number reaches 100, it stops being updated!
                sign="minus";
            else {
                if (sign=="plus")
                    number++;
                else
                    number--;
            }
        } 
        cout << number; // <-- counts to 100 and then keeps outputting 100
        usleep(3000); 
    } 
}
```

To fix that, you need logic that is more like the following instead:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

int main () { 
    int number = 1; 
    string sign = "plus"; 
    for (int i = 700; i > 0; i--) { 
        cout << number; 
        if (number==0)
            sign="plus";
        else if (number==100)
            sign="minus";
        if (sign=="plus")
            number++;
        else
            number--;
        usleep(3000); 
    } 
}
```